# where could my disk space be if it is not sparse, deleted or hidden by a mount point

Tags: disk-usage

I appear to have lost a couple of GB in an ext4 root filesystem (under llvm on centos 7.1 in a VMWare ESX VM if that matters).

```
[someone@somewhere ~]$ sudo du -xsm /
4561    /
```

yet:

```
[someone@somewhere ~]$ sudo df -m /
Filesystem                 1M-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_sys-lv_root      8944  7562       956  89% /
```

I thought maybe something was under a mount point, so I tried this:

```
[someone@somewhere ~]$ sudo mount --bind / /vp
[someone@somewhere ~]$ sudo du -xsm /vp
4561    /vp
```

Maybe a deleted file still in use by a process:

```
sudo lsof | grep deleted
```

Doesn't show anything significant.

Nor does looking for sparse files using the following command as root (command found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86442/finding-sparse-files)):

```
find / -type f ! -size 0 -exec perl -le 'for(@ARGV){open(A,"<",$_)or next;seek A,0,4;$p=tell A;seek A,0,2;print if$p!=tell A;close A}' {} +
```

So, where else could my data be, what does df know that du doesn't in this case? I also checked df -i and less than half the inodes are in use.

Comment: Have you read through [Why are there so many different ways to measure disk usage?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120312)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other possible explanations:

- you're in a `chroot` or mount namespace and don't have access to the whole filesystem. You could tell by running `ls -id /` which gives `2` if you're not in a `chroot`/mount namespace.
- The file system is corrupted.
- The space is in use by one of the [special inodes](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Special_inodes). You can use `debugfs` and issue some `stat <3>`, `stat <4>`... to verify.
- The space is in use by a deleted file, that deleted file is open by a process in another pid namespace (and you're not in the root pid namespace).
- The space is in use by a deleted file, that deleted file is not open by any file, but is for instance connected to a loop device (`losetup -a` to check).

Note that there's no reason sparse files would contribute to the discrepancy between `du` and `df`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, sadly, the only one I can't rule out is 'The file system is corrupted.' Time to restore a backup and hope this doesn't happen again I guess.

Comment: @jankeir, does it do it as well after a reboot? Have you tried a fsck to check whether it's actually corrupted? You can do a fsck on a lvm snapshot if you don't want to reboot.

Comment: We booted a vmware snapshot with a rescue disk iso and there the filesystem usage was normal and a fsck didn't show any issues, so we rebooted the machine and it's fine now. Not sure what caused our problem but I'll accept your answer as it does answer the question about where disk space could be.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things the file system could spend disk space for, which are not related to file contents.

`df` takes the number of used and available blocks directly from the file system, while `du` just sums the size of blocks allocated to each file, so any unrelated FS data structures are not accounted.

It's totally ok that `du` shows less used space than `df` does. The strange thing is that the difference is so huge, especially for a rarely modified root partition. Have you tuned your FS somehow? Have you also tried `du --inodes` to compare with `df -i`?

Comment: Hmm, there's a small difference between df -i and du --inodes: `du --inodes -sx / ` gives 30800, `df -i /` gives 31642.

Comment: @jankeir small difference here is fine