# Tell if a file is a "sparse file"

Tags: ext4, sparse-files

There is an existing question for ["Finding all sparse files"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86442/finding-sparse-files), and I think I could use it, but the scripts were too complex to understand. I don't think the GUI of Ubuntu file manager provides a way to know whether a file is sparse or not. How to tell?

The file system is EXT4.

Comment: The accepted answer there is quite straightforward -- a one-liner. The `find` part will need to be tailored for your requirements -- as posted, it searches all files from the root directory. The format after the -printf uses %S to show the estimated proportion of 'real' data blocks, and %p to show the pathname. This is piped to an awk script which only lists the files that use fewer disk blocks than a non-sparse file of the same size would need.

Comment: [My answer there](/a/86446) gives code that does just that (and more reliably than `gfind -printf %S` approaches). In which way does it not address your question?

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is a one-liner:

```
# find / -type f -printf "%S\t%p\n" | gawk '$1 < 1.0 {print}'
```

So there's a number of parts to this.  Let's break it down:

```
find / -type f
```

This part will search all files on the machine

```
-printf "%S\t\%p\n"
```

This part will print out the "sparsiness" of the file and the complete filename.

So the output, at this point will look like a list of entries in the following format:

```
1.23456 /tmp/a/file
```

If the first number is less than 1.0 then the file is considered "sparse".

So then we can filter this through awk:

```
gawk '$1 < 1.0 {print}'
```

This will limit the output to only the lines which are sparse by only reporting on those where the first number is < 1.0

The result is a list of all the files that are sparse, along with their "sparsiness".

That's a lot of work for a simple command!

If you just want to test to see if a specific file is sparse then you can use a variation of this.  e.g.

```
find file_to_test -printf "%S"
```

will return a number.  That can be tested to be < 1.0

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I am not trying to "search for files". I am trying to check if a specific file is sparse file or not. Let's say that the file name is "test.img". How can I check if "test.img" is sparse or not?

Comment: That's what the last section of the answer explains; `find test.img -printf "%S"`.  If the answer is less than 1 then it's a sparse file.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to check it on the terminal?

```
find FILENAME -type f ! -size 0 -printf '%S\n'
```

If it prints something less than 1 it's a sparse file.

Comment: Bash (IIRC) does not understand non-integer arithmetic (hence the use of awk in previous answers). This may work in ksh, however.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed that part because it is better answered by Stephen Harris.