# Why does size increase after I copy?

Tags: mount, cp, size

I'm copying a directory from one mount point to another, yet I see a size increase between the two and I'm wondering why that is.

My first mount point is named /home/directory/mount1, and inside it I have a "bin" directory, where, when I do `du -hs bin`, I see it has a size of 7.9 M. I copy this over to /home/directory/mount2 using `cp -ap bin /home/directory/mount2` from inside /home/directory/mount1. Then, however, when I do `du -hs bin` inside /home/directory/mount2, I get a size of 8.3M!

I'm logged in as root and from what I can tell, the exact same files in the mount1 bin directory were copied over to mount2. What is with the size discrepancy? It was also present when I did `cp -r bin /home/directory/mount2`.

Edit: Upon further examination, every file in the contents of bin in mount2 is 4K larger than its equivalent in mount1/bin.

Comment: The answers for http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106275/du-gives-two-different-results-for-the-same-file give some reasons why this can happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the link in your comment, JigglyNaga. From there I found that my command `du -hs bin` shows the disk usage of the contents of the directory. There are actually two separate images mounted on each of the two mount points (mount1 is partitioned, mount2 is just a pure ext3 filesystem).

According to the link in the comment, if I want to check the size of a file or directory on its own without relating to disk space, I can use `ls -l` or `du -b`. Doing this, the size of bin and all its contents are the same for both mount points. I will use these commands from now on. Thanks!