# How to list files with only name and size

Tags: shell, files, size

I would like to list the content of a directory, 1 line per entry, with only the files names and the files sizes.

`ls -l` shows too much information.

`ls -1 -s` doesn't show a file's size but its allocation (--block-size=1 doesn't change that)

I cannot find a command line argument that makes ls do what I want... is there one?

If not, what would be a good, short and robust solution to make that kind of listing?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) tell us what operating system you are using so we know what tools are available and ii) specify why you want this: is it just so you can see it on the terminal or do you need to process the output somehow?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit odd solution. You can use `du` command:

```
du -s *
```

will list size and name of files and **directories**

Comment: `du` will display blocks (disk usage) while some `stat` or the `-printf "%s"` of the `find` command will show bytes. There is `du -b` but I am not sure if it can always matches the size (see man page), or if it is portable.

Comment: @thanasisp, no, `du -b` is not portable. Do not exist in AIX, Solaris...

Comment: Then it can't print the byte size, but blocks, e.g. for a file with 1 byte it would say 4 (4K)

Comment: @thanasisp, wrong. For linux AFAIK you will get size in kB, for AIX, Solaris, HP-UX you will get it in 512 bytes blocks.

Comment: (The `4K` is an example ("`e.g.`"), whatever the block-size is). For example what `du -s file` prints for you, for a text file having only 1 character?

Comment: @thanasisp, it depend of filesystem. For some extend based it may give you the precise size. :)

Comment: It will not give byte size. Because it is "disk usage". The block is reserved for this file, so it counts as "usage". It is not byte count. See also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106275/du-gives-two-different-results-for-the-same-file).

Comment: @thanasisp, did you miss my previous comment? **some extent based (filesystems)**....

Comment: I try your command `du -s file` with a text file of 1 byte/character on GNU/Linux (ext4) and I get output: `4 file`. with `du -sh` I see `4.0K file`. Could you please report the output for your OS?

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
stat -Ln +size -- *
```

With GNU `find` and `sort`:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.*' -printf '%f %s\0' |
  sort -z |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```