# What are functions to manipulate sparse files under Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, rsync, inode, sparse-files

What are functions to manipulate sparse files under Linux? (let's say in C, notes about other systems highly welcome)
e.g.:

- make hole inside of file by removing part of its inside
- investigate structure , e.g. generate sequence of pairs denoting beginnings and ends of separated continuous blocks of data
- split file into two at some point, by reassigning range of blocks (i.e. without moving actual data)
- investigate inodes, and other relevant aspects? (maybe possible to assign some blocks to multiple files in copy-on-write manner?)

---

Context:

Original question that come to my mind and I arrived from was after `man rsync` of `--sparse` option:

Why `rsync`'s `--sparse` option conflicts with `--inplace` ?

Is it limitation of filesystem calls api?

From data structure point of view, if source sparse file is seen as sequence of non-continuous blocks of data, than I would expect from "r"syncing to deallocate on destination those ranges that does not exist at source, allocate missing ones, rest update accordingly (even with standard rsync rolling hash algorithm, treating all remaining sequences as one, or running separately on each).

Reference:

```
man rsync
```

> ```
>    -S, --sparse
>           Try to handle sparse files efficiently so they take up less space on the destination.  Conflicts with --inplace because it's
> ```
>
> not  possible  to  over-
>                 write data in a sparse fashion.

Comment: For your first two points, have a look at fallocate, punchhole, fiemap.

Comment: thanks to suggestions, I've found fiemap related ans: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47450/9689

Comment: Related: [Finding sparse files?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/86442)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sparse files are designed to be transparent to userspace: holes are created by seeking past unused areas, and are read as blocks of zeroes. They can’t be detected using standard userspace APIs, at least not yet — as [pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366373/what-are-functions-to-manupulate-sparse-files-under-linux/366378#comment650777_366378) by [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas), at least Solaris and Linux support the `SEEK_DATA` and `SEEK_HOLE` [`lseek(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) flags which allow userspace programs to find holes, and these flags might be [added to POSIX](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=415) at some point.

This explains the incompatibility between `rsync`’ `--sparse` and `--inplace` options: when writing to an existing file *portably*, holes can’t be created in existing data. `--sparse` works by rewriting the whole file, skipping over (long) sequences of zeroes, which results in sparse files on OSs and file systems which support them.

On Linux, you can retrieve details of files’ sparseness using the [`fiemap` ioctl](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/fiemap.txt), and `e2fsprogs`’ [`filefrag(8)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/filefrag.8.html); see [Detailed sparse file information on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6978/86440). On the writing side, you can use [`fallocate(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) (and the handy [`fallocate(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fallocate.1.html) utility) to punch holes in an existing file, making it sparse if the holes cover entire blocks. Support is file system dependent — only XFS, btrfs, ext4, and tmpfs currently support these operations. Recent kernels (since 4.1) and *very* recent versions of `util-linux` support inserting holes in files, shifting the content after the hole (`fallocate -i`, introduced in `util-linux` 2.30 which should be released soon).

Your last two questions are file system surgery, and I’m not sure there’s any generic system call or ioctl available to perform such operations. `reflink`-compatible file systems allow files to share their contents; this can be achieved using [the `FICLONE`and `FICLONERANGE` ioctls](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_ficlone.2.html).

Comment: I hadn't realised the `-i` was not released yet. I happened to spot it in the man page after pulling the latest code for something else.

Comment: I'm looking forward to the day `rsync` supports SEEK_HOLE/SEEK_DATA/FIEMAP. I've been hit a few times by it hanging on a several TB sparse file.