# Why is the the apparent size of a file much larger than the actual disk usage in this case? (4.4GiB vs. 512B)

Tags: filesystems, size, lustre, ncdu

While browsing folders via `ncdu`, I noticed that the apparent size of a file was sometimes much larger than the actual disk usage. Example via `ncdu`, then `a` to toggle between showing disk usage and showing apparent, then `i` to show more details:

[image]

I was told this may be due to some automatic process that only keeps a small portion of the data in a "fast" layer and and keeps the rest on slower place such as AWS S3.  How can I check that?

---

As [suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/771965/why-is-the-the-apparent-size-of-a-file-much-larger-than-the-actual-disk-usage-in?noredirect=1#comment1473737_771965) by [Chris Down](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/10762/chris-down), here is part of the output of `hexdump` run on that file:

[image]

It seems to indicate the file isn't sparse.

As [suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/771965/why-is-the-the-apparent-size-of-a-file-much-larger-than-the-actual-disk-usage-in#comment1473744_771965) by [Artem S. Tashkinov](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/260833/artem-s-tashkinov), the file system is [Lustre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lustre_(file_system)) (checked with `sudo df -T`).

Comment: That explanation sounds bogus, unless you are using FUSE or similar and the implementation is blatantly lying. Most likely this file is sparse. What does it actually look like if you view the hexdump?

Comment: @ChrisDown Thanks, not sparse it seems: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPA2Q.jpg

Comment: Soft/Hard link maybe? Some weird FUSE fs?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks, [Lustre fs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lustre_(file_system)).

Comment: That hex dump shows fewer than 512 bytes. Are there more non-zero bytes?

Comment: Since it's a virtual network (!) FS all bets are off. It's impossible to say how much these files actually occupy because files on this FS are not files per se, they are "objects" and can be physically stored anywhere.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks, no it looks like it's not a sparse file.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Looks like the folders are in partition using the [Amazon FSx for Lustre file system](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fsx/latest/LustreGuide/create-dra-linked-data-repo.html). What explains why the disk usage is high for some files and low for others? E.g., on https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Eni.jpg bottom row, disk usage is a 62.1 GB while apparent size is 461 GB. Are the 62.1 GB some local cache?

Comment: *Are the 62.1 GB some local cache?* could be.

Answer (score 4):

This is usual (but non-obvious) behaviour on [hierarchical storage systems such as Lustre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lustre_(file_system)#HSM_(Hierarchical_Storage_Management)). `ncdu` and other sparseness-measuring tools generally rely on the value given in [`st_blocks`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html) in response to a [`stat` call](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html). On historical, non-copy-on-write file systems, the obvious behaviour is the one we’ve grown to expect: each file occupies on disk at least the exact amount of non-zero data it contains, so `st_blocks` indicates at least the amount of actual non-zero data stored in the file. In Lustre, `st_blocks` represents the storage used on the frontend system, not the overall amount of data stored in the file.

There is just one slight exception to this: “released” files (whose contents are entirely removed from frontend storage) indicate that they occupy 512 bytes, not 0. This was implemented [as a workaround for an issue with tools such as `tar`](https://jira.whamcloud.com/browse/LU-3864) which will skip reading files with 0 `st_blocks` entirely, resulting in data loss on Lustre-based file systems (archiving a released file with sparse file detection, which is common in backup scenarios, would end up storing no data at all). When a file indicates that it occupies 512 bytes, tools have to read it (or use [`fiemap` ioctls etc.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/366378/86440)) to determine exactly what it contains; on Lustre such actions prompt the file’s data to be retrieved from wherever it is stored in the hierarchy.

With huge files, it’s unusual for the entire file to be restored to frontend storage, which is why you only end up with a partial “occupied block count” in some scenarios.