# Why does reading a file with hexdump sometimes change find's sparseness value (%S)?

Tags: find, sparse-files, lustre

I use a Lustre file system. I've noticed that if I look at the find's sparseness value (`%S`) for a file, then print the file with `hexdump`, then look at the find's sparseness value  again, then sometimes find's sparseness value (`%S`) has changed. Why does it change?

---

Command to look at the find's sparseness value (`%S`) for the file `myvideo.mp4`:

```
find myvideo.mp4 -printf "%S"
```

Command to read the file `myvideo.mp4` with `hexdump`:

```
hexdump myvideo.mp4
```

---

I noticed that behavior on several files. Examples of changes of find's sparseness values (`%S`):

- `0.000135559` to `0.631297`
- `0.00466808` to `0.228736`

Is it because the file is being cached partly locally when reading with `hexdump`? I noticed that this change isn't specific to `hexdump`, e.g. the same happens with `nano` (and likely any other program that read the file):

```
dernoncourt@server:/videos$ find myvideo.mp4 -printf "%S"
0.00302331
dernoncourt@server:/videos$ nano myvideo.mp4 
dernoncourt@server:/videos$ find myvideo.mp4 -printf "%S"
0.486752
```

Comment: From the manual about `%S`: *This is calculated as '(BLOCKSIZE\*st_blocks /
     st_size)'*. (diskusage/apparentsize) So it's going to be the same reasons as in your other question.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks, I also voted to close the question but in hindsight a short answer repeating the first sentence of your comment+ a link to the other questions explaining the apparent size variations would be useful I think.

Comment: I'll let you do it.

Answer (score 1):

(All the information in this answer comes from
[Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas)'s [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/771983/why-does-reading-a-file-with-hexdump-sometimes-change-finds-sparseness-value#comment1473888_771983). Thanks!)

From [find's man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) (formatting is mine):

> `%S`: **File's sparseness. This is calculated as (`BLOCKSIZE*st_blocks / st_size`). The exact value you will get for an ordinary file of a certain length is system-dependent.** However, normally sparse files will have values less than 1.0, and files which use indirect blocks may have a value which is greater than 1.0. The value used for `BLOCKSIZE` is system-dependent, but is usually 512 bytes. If the file size is zero, the value printed is undefined. On systems which lack support for `st_blocks`, a file's sparseness is assumed to be 1.0.

Note that:

- `BLOCKSIZE*st_blocks` corresponds to the disk usage,
- `st_size` corresponds to the apparent size.

Therefore, `%S` = `BLOCKSIZE*st_blocks / st_size` = `diskusage/apparentsize`.

Furthermore, this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/772007/16704) addresses why the apparent size of a file is sometimes much larger than the actual disk usage on [hierarchical storage systems such as Lustre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lustre_(file_system)#HSM_(Hierarchical_Storage_Management)) even though it may not be sparse at all. It also mentions that it’s unusual for a large file to be entirely restored to frontend storage.

Since files are sometimes being partly restored to frontend storage when read with some programs such as `hexdump` or `nano`, it increases the `st_blocks` value, which decreases `%S (=BLOCKSIZE*st_blocks / st_size)`, which means the file's sparseness reported by `find` (`%S`) decreases.

---

Since `find myvideo.mp4 -printf "%S"` is useless to know if a file  is sparse on a Lustre file system, one can use the following [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86448/16704) by [frostschutz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/30851/frostschutz) to know if a file is sparse:

```
file = "myvideo.mp4"
if [ "$((`stat -c '%b*%B-%s' -- "$file"`))" -lt 0 ]
then
    echo "$file" is sparse
else
    echo "$file" is not sparse
fi
```

Note that this solution has a few limitations, as noted in the [comment section](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86448/16704).

Also, note that Lustre [does not](https://www.mail-archive.com/lustre-discuss@lists.lustre.org/msg14496.html) directly support the `SEEK_HOLE/SEEK_DATA` interface currently, so we can't use [solutions using that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86446/16704) to know if a file sparse on Lustre.